# Vue js and VS code - no Intellisense for absolute file path

Tags: vue.js, import, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have an app created using vue-cli 3 and I am using Visual Studio as my IDE. I have installed Vetur extension. Unfortunately when I am typing something like that

```
import Message from '@/components/Message'
```

VS code does not provide any Intellisense for resolving such an absolute file path. Maybe VS code does not understand that @ maps to 'src' folder in projects created using vue-cli. Does anybody know how to solve that problem?

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 17):

I have setup `jsconfig.json` in following manner and it works

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added this code in `tsconfig.json`, but still the imports are not recognized.

Comment: it worked but the path is the relative path

Comment: If this does not work right away, try refreshing the VS Code by using `Reload Windows` (i.e. by holding `command` + `shift` + `P`, then search and select `Developer: Reload Window`

Comment: This will also work if VS Code `go to` functions are not working (i.e. right-click on the function name and select `Go To Definition` _OR_ hold `command` and `click` on a function name to go to its definition)

Comment: If you got an error in VS code on line `"src/*"` i.e. `Non-relative paths are not allowed` use  `"baseUrl": "."` inside `compilerOptions` (e.g. above `paths` object) as your `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` must be at the root of the project

Comment: Add baseUrl along with paths

"compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
          "@/*": [
            "src/*"
          ]
        }
    }

Answer (score 7):

You 'd be needing a `jsconfig.json` file for the Intellisense to kick in with webpack aliases. You can check the linked article.

https://medium.com/@justintulk/solve-module-import-aliasing-for-webpack-jest-and-vscode-74007ce4adc9

Answer (score 0):

I could get the eslint to not complain about it by:

1. install eslint-import-resolver-webpack (dev dependency)
2. add a webpack.config.js in the root of my project with the content:

   const path = require('path'); // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies

   module.exports = {
   resolve: {
   alias: {
   '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
   },
   extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
   },
   };
3. in .eslintrs.js:

   rules: {
   'import/extensions': [
   'error',
   'always',
   {
   js: 'never',
   vue: 'never',
   },
   ],
   },
   settings: {
   'import/resolver': {
   webpack: {
   config: 'webpack.config.js',
   },
   },
   },

I still would like to have the Intellisense working, but for now I will continue just doing that. Already lost more time than I should in this problem.